# How to truncate a numpy array for values greater than a specified value?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Similar to [this Matlab question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23227149/truncating-an-array), I am wondering how to truncate a numpy array by cutting off the values greater than a certain threshold value.  The values of the array in question are in ascending order.

```
import numpy as np
a=np.linspace(1,10,num=10)
truncatevalue = 5.5
```

How would I produce an array that has the values of `a` that are less than `truncatevalue` and would only include those values?  In this case, the resulting array would be

```
a_truncated=([1., 2., 3., 4., 5.])
```

**Bonus:** I actually have two arrays I would like to truncate based on the values in one of the arrays.

```
import numpy as np
a=np.linspace(1,10,num=10)
b=np.array([19, 17, 15, 14, 29, 33, 28, 4, 90, 6])
truncatevalue = 5.5
```

`b` is an arbitrary array, I just chose some numbers for a definite example.  I would like to truncate `b` in the same way that `a` gets truncated, so that the result would be

```
a_truncated=([1., 2., 3., 4., 5.])
b_truncated=([19, 17, 15, 14, 29])
```

I don't know if it will be as simple as just repeating what needs to be done to get `a_truncated` or not, so I wanted to include it as well in case there is something different that needs to be done.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use boolean indexing:

```
>>> a = np.linspace(1, 10, num=10)
>>> truncatevalue = 5.5
>>> a_truncated = a[a < truncatevalue]
>>> a_truncated
array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.])
```

Essentially, `a < truncatevalue` returns a boolean array indicating whether or not the element of `a` meets the condition. Using this boolean array to index `a` returns a view of `a` in which each element's index is `True`.

So for the second part of your question, all you need to do is this:

```
>>> b = np.array([19, 17, 15, 14, 29, 33, 28, 4, 90, 6])
>>> b_truncated = b[a < truncatevalue]
>>> b_truncated
array([19, 17, 15, 14, 29])
```

Comment: Do you need `a_truncated = a[a < truncatevalue]`?

Comment: @Joshua - To return either `a_truncated` or `b_truncated` in your example, all you need is the boolean array `a < truncatevalue`. As long as `a`, `b` and `truncatevalue` are defined you can find either array. (You don't need to assign `a_truncated` to `a[a < truncatevalue]` first.)

Answer (score -3):

```
a_truncated = [value for value in a if value < truncateValue]
```